# Question deleted under RemoveDeadQuestions does not show negative score at deletion time

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-accounts, timeline, auto-delete

A question deleted under RemoveDeadQuestions does not show negative vote at deletion time.  From the [question timeline](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/posts/15938/timeline) (link needs mod access on Earth Science SE):

[image: screenshot of question timeline]

At score 0, it should be [removed after a year (`RemoveAbandonedQuestions`), rather than after a month (`RemoveDeadQuestions`)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/172266).  What's going on here?

One hypothesis: it was scored at -1 at 2019-02-23, but the user who had downvoted has since deleted their account, and the downvote got reverted after the question was deleted.  How do votes by users who deleted their account show up in the timeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hypothesis is correct - there was an active downvote on the question at the time when the deletion checks ran, and the user who cast it was deleted a few months later.

Votes by deleted users don't show up in the timeline because, outside of special circumstances, votes are deleted at the same time as the user.